# tensorflow CNN mnist example training accuracy drops to 0.06 from 1 unexpectedly with large iteration

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent, mnist

The training accuracy drops to 0.06 from 1 unexpectedly after 26700 iterations. The code was got from tensorflow's online doc, and I simply modified the filter size from 5x5 to 3x3 ,iterations from 20000 to 100000, and batch size from 50 to 100. Can any body explain this? <del>It may be related to AdamOptimizer, because if change it to GradientDesentOptimizer it doesn't happen even 56200 iterations.But I'm not sure.</del> GradientDesentOptimizer also has this problem.

```
step 26400, training accuracy 1, loss 0.00202696
step 26500, training accuracy 1, loss 0.0750173
step 26600, training accuracy 1, loss 0.0790716
step 26700, training accuracy 1, loss 0.0136688
step 26800, training accuracy 0.06, loss nan
step 26900, training accuracy 0.03, loss nan
step 27000, training accuracy 0.12, loss nan
step 27100, training accuracy 0.08, loss nan
```

The python code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

def weight_varible(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
print("Download Done!")

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# paras
W_conv1 = weight_varible([3, 3, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

# conv layer-1
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

# conv layer-2
W_conv2 = weight_varible([3, 3, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# full connection
W_fc1 = weight_varible([7 * 7 * 64, 1204])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1204])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

# dropout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

# output layer: softmax
W_fc2 = weight_varible([1204, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

# model training
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y_conv, 1), tf.arg_max(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(100000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

    if i % 10 == 0:
        train_accuacy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        train_cross_entropy = cross_entropy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g, loss %g"%(i, train_accuacy, train_cross_entropy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict = {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

# accuacy on test
save_path = saver.save(sess, "./mnist.model")
#saver.restore(sess,"./mnist.model")
print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
print("test accuracy %g"%(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0})))
```

Answer (score 3):

I actually just ran into this issue with a CNN I was training where after a point in optimization it would nan everything out.  What I think is going on is a numeric stability issue with the log in the cost function.  When the network starts to make prediction with high confidence (meaning this issue becomes more likely as the network trains and achieves lower cost) the y_conv vectors will look like `y_conv = [1, 0]` (ignoring batching).  This would mean log of `log(y_conv) = log([1, 0]) = [0, -inf]`.  Say that the [1, 0] was also correct so when you do `y_ * tf.log(y_conv)` you are really doing `[1, 0] * [0, -inf] = [0, nan]` since it does not know how to multiply 0 and infinity.  Adding these costs results in a nan cost.  I think you could fix this by adding some sort of small epislon to the log like `y_ * tf.log(y_conv + 1e-5)`.  I seem to have fixed my issue using the `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(...)` which seems to take care of the numerical issues.

Comment: thx.  1.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() works well. After 50000 iterations I got a test accuracy of 99.3%.  2.notice that it's very memory costy (about 5GB) during computing the accuracy of test set.